# VB.NET Writing MSSQL data to DBF format

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to export MS-SQL data to [DBF format](http://whatis.techtarget.com/fileformat/DBF-dBASE-file).
Is there anyway to achieve this as I can't find any solution to this?
I am using **SQL Server 2008 Express R2** in **Visual Studio 2008**.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this link:
https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/export-data-from-mssql-to-dbf-using-vb-net.1239926/

> Hi,
>
> This is not as easy as you might suppose. I do it frequently, but I first
>   have to create the structure of the .dbf table I want to generate and then I
>   place it with an _ in the name in a designated subdirectory. The reason I
>   have to do this is because the odbc driver for ado .net is limited in the
>   datatypes it will create, so I can't very well fashion the .dbf file
>   directly inside .net.
>
> The function below does the rest - it turns a given dataset into a .dbf
>   file, as you are trying to do; I simply pass the dataset, the .dbf name and
>   the number of columns to it.
>
> ```
> Public Function tabletodbf(ByVal mtable As DataSet, ByRef mdbf As String, ByVal numcols As Integer) As Integer
>     ' suppositions: the dbf file is in f:\imcapps\dbffiles; also, there is
>     ' an empty of it with a _ at the end of the filename; also, we are working
>     ' with dbf files exclusively in f:\imcapps\dbffiles; also, the table and
>     ' the dbf have to have the exact same structure and in the same column #
>     ' sequence; also, if the _ causes
>     ' the file name to be too large, this probably won't work, so I have to
>     ' ensure this doesn't happen
>     ' signature:
>     ' dim funcs as new imcfunctionlib.functions
>     ' dim xint as integer
>     ' xint = funcs.tabletodbf(dspslips, "netcsv.dbf", 5)
>     ' xint = funcs.tabletodbf(dsletsumtt2, "letsumtt.dbf", 27)
>     tabletodbf = 0
>     Dim oconn_ As New SqlConnection("data source=d5z0071;database=imc;integrated security=sspi;")
>     Dim oconn_d_ As New OdbcConnection("Driver={Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)};UID=admin;usercommitsync=yes;threads=3;statistics=0;safetransaction s=0;pagetimeout=5;maxscanrows=8;maxbuffersize=2048;FIL=dBaseIV;DriverID=533;deleted=0;defaultdir=f:\imcapps\dbffiles;dbq=f:\imcapps\dbffiles;collatingsequence=ascii;")
>     oconn_.Open()
>     oconn_d_.Open()
>     Dim path As String = "f:\imcapps\dbffiles\" & mdbf
>     Dim underscorename As String
>     underscorename = Mid(mdbf, 1, mdbf.Length - 4) & "_.dbf"
>     Dim fi As FileInfo = New FileInfo(path)
>     If fi.Exists = True Then
>         Kill("f:\imcapps\dbffiles\" & mdbf)
>     End If
>     FileCopy("f:\imcapps\dbffiles\" & underscorename, "f:\imcapps\dbffiles\" & mdbf)
>     ' always save an empty file with _ as a convention
>     Dim da_d As New OdbcDataAdapter("select * from f:\imcapps\dbffiles\" & mdbf, oconn_d_)
>     Dim ds_d As New DataSet("_d")
>     da_d.Fill(ds_d, "_d")
>     Dim commandbuilder_ds_d As OdbcCommandBuilder = New OdbcCommandBuilder(da_d)
>     Dim i As Integer
>     Dim irow, mrow_d As DataRow
>     For Each irow In mtable.Tables(0).Rows
>         mrow_d = ds_d.Tables(0).NewRow()
>         For i = 0 To numcols - 1
>             mrow_d(i) = irow(i)
>         Next
>         ds_d.Tables("_d").Rows.Add(mrow_d)
>     Next
>     Try
>         da_d.Update(ds_d, "_d")
>     Catch ex As Exception
>         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
>     End Try
>     oconn_.Close()
>     oconn_d_.Close()
>     tabletodbf = 1
> End Function
> ```

I am not so sure... you may try if it works.